# How do I retrieve data from Java to sqlite to check if the data has already exist and update if the data matched

Tags: java, database, sqlite

for example, I have created a program to change a user password but when I click 'change' there's nothing happened and there is no error I received. What do you think I missed from here? Thanks in advance

```
private void changeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
String user, pass, newp;
user = username.getText();
pass = password.getText();
newp = newpass.getText();
String sql = "select * from Login where username='" + user + "'";
String sql1 = "update Login set password= '" + newp + "' where username='" + user + "'";
try {
    //Connection.rs=Connection.pst.executeQuery(sql);
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.executeQuery(sql);
    if (rs.next()) {
        if (rs.getString("password").equals(pass)) {
            // newp.setText("");
            pst.executeUpdate(sql1);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password Changed!");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid username or password", "Access Denied", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong username!");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code, the main being the try/catch block which suppresses any error message so that you can't understand what you are doing wrong.

You can't execute 2 different sql statements with the same `PreparedStatement` object, but this is what you do.
So define one for the `SELECT` statement and another for the `UPDATE` statement.
Also, use `?` placeholders for the parameters that you pass to the sql statements instead of concatenating them and pass them via the `setString()` method.
 This is the proper and safe way to use prepared statements.

Try this:

```
private void changeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String user = username.getText();
    String pass = password.getText();
    String newp = newpass.getText();

    String sqlSelect = "select * from Login where username = ?";
    PreparedStatement pstSelect = conn.prepareStatement(sqlSelect);
    pstSelect.setString(1, user);
    ResultSet rs = pstSelect.executeQuery();

    if (rs.next()) {
        if (rs.getString("password").equals(pass)) {
            String sqlUpdate = "update Login set password = ? where username = ?";
            PreparedStatement pstUpdate = conn.prepareStatement(sqlUpdate); 
            pstUpdate.setString(1, newp);
            pstUpdate.setString(2, user);
            pstUpdate.executeUpdate();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password Changed!");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid username or password", "Access Denied", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong username!");
    }
}
```

Comment: The code worked, but I am now facing a much difficult problem of "database is locked" even though I already closed the connection to the SQL. I already faced this problem before but I can still search for data in a database, after I search for data, I could see now the data loaded in a table, but now it won't loaded.

Comment: ok I think I solved the problem by adding another catch statement to close the connection to the database, although I don't know why it worked, I guess... I used two connections in this program and I should also close two connections to properly close it.

Comment: @Byakuran fine if it worked and don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark.